# Lacos while em javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar um laço while que enviei uma mensagem um número x de vezes para o console.

```
var loop = function(){
    while(){
        console.log("");
    }
}

loop();
```

Comment: Se vc ja tem o numero x de vezes por que não usar um for() ?

Comment: Sim, usar o for seria mais fácil mesmo, porém gostaria de aprender como funcionaria fazer essa mesma questão que daria de ser feita com o for só que com o while.

Answer (score 3):

Basta criar uma condição:

```js
var loop = function(x) {
  qtd = 0;
  while (qtd < x) {
    console.log("Mensagem #" + qtd);
    qtd++;
  }
}

loop(10);
```